# Rails ActiveStorage vs AWS S3 tiers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

My application stores MANY MANY images in S3 - we use Rails 5.2 ActiveStorage for that. The images are used a lot for 6 to 9 months. Then they are used VERY rarely until they are 15 months old and deleted automatically by ActiveStorage.

To save some money I'd like to move the files from 'S3-Standard' to 'S3-Infrequent Access (S3-IA)' after 9months of the file creation (This can be done automatically in AWS).

My question is: Will ActiveStorage still be able to find/display the image in 'S3-IA' in the rare case someone wants to see it? Will ActiveStorage still be able to find the file to delete it at 15months. Bottom Line: I don't want ActiveStorage to loose track of the file when it goes from 'S3-Standard' to 'S3-IA'

Comment: Heck, after 12 months I might want to move the image from 'S3-IA' to 'S3-One Zone-Infrequent Access' which is even cheaper.

Comment: Not considering Glacier. All images are above 128K.

Answer (score 1):

S3-IA just changes the pricing of an object. It doesn't change the visibility of the object, or the time needed to retrieve it (unlike GLACIER storage class).

One thing to be aware of is that IA pricing is based on a minimum object size of 128k. If you have a lot of objects that are smaller, then your costs may actually increase if you save them as IA.

[docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html#sc-compare)

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tested, but Active Storage should be able to find the object as long as its name doesn’t change.